# Logging oracle database operations by using entity

Tags: sql, oracle, entity-framework, log4net

I want to log database operations on my code side. I can do it when my database is sql but for oracle it doesnt work.

Here is my sample code for SQL logging;

```
 private MyEntities GetDBContext(IContext arg) {
        var db = new MyEntities();
        db.Database.Log = EntityFrameworkLogger;
        return db;
    }

    public static void EntityFrameworkLogger(string log) {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(log) || log.StartsWith("--")) { return; }
        logger.DebugFormat("SQL : {0}", log);
    }
```

For oracle;

```
db.Database.Log
```

doesnt work.(There is no method db.Database.Log) What can i use instead of this part, what do you recommend?

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of "doesn't work" - throws an exception, silently fails ..?

Comment: There is any method like db.Database.Log

Comment: Which base class are you using for your Oracle's DbContext?

Comment: I use entityframework 5.0 for it.